# How do we deal with questions that don't state whether repetition is allowed or not?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Just like the question, in most books there are questions that don't state whether repetition is allowed or not. How do we deal with it? Do I need to compute it as if repetition is allowed then as if repetition is not allowed?

Example:

Using the vowels of the English alphabet, how many different possible 3-letter code words can be formed?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: @YujieZha sure.

Comment: Codes and words usually allow repetition implicitly (which means that in this case, your question is more of a language question than a math question). But the best approach is probably to begin the answer with "I assume we allow repeated letters." and then proceed with calculations.

Comment: Good question, but is it a math question?.  The answer is perhaps, people are usually not imaginative enough to understand what other people don't know, or understand, or assume.

Comment: My recommendation is to learn how to solve all interpretations of the problem including but not limited to: order matters/doesn't matter, repetition allowed/not allowed, leading zeroes allowed/not allowed (*e.g. six digit strings versus six digit numbers*).  If solving a problem for practice, it doesn't really matter which interpretation it is.  If solving a problem for yourself, you will know which interpretation is intended.  If solving a problem on a test, you are encouraged to ask for clarification from the proctor/teacher during the test on which interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: If repetitions were ***not***  allowed, the question would have probably been worded more like: "*how many different possible 3-letter code words can be formed using* ***distinct*** *vowels of the English alphabet*".

Comment: Just to say, the language surrounding probability and combinatorics is often ambiguous.  Sometimes it's good practice to work both (or all) possible meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the plain meaning of the words in the question, and think about examples.

Would a string of characters with repetition make sense as a "code word", in the common sense of the phrase?  Would AAA be something you would call a code word?  How about BOB?

It seems clear to me that the answer is yes, so repetition is allowed here.